# I'm trying to create a feature, and I need help getting started

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to build a webpage with an interactive feature, but I don't know where to begin looking.  I think it'll be driven by jQuery, but I'm now sure.

What I want is: I want a page where (for the sake of this description) I have a 700px wide by 500px tall box.  At the bottom of the box(div) I have a 5 button navigation(images just to make it easy).  I want it so that when I click a button in the bottom nav, a div with the content for that specific "page/button" expands Up from the navigation at the bottom. Then when you click a different button, that div rolls back down, then the next one expands up.

I saw some stuff about CSS3 animations, but I'm not sure how I would implement it using that either...

Can anybody point me in the right direction for what tools to make this using.  Or if it's been done before, a tutorial for implementing it myself?

Comment: You could look into a Javascript framework, like [backbone.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418369/what-is-backbone-js).

Comment: Don't use Backbone until you can use JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're new to this, so I'd recommend taking it slow. If you already know HTML alright and some Javascript, learn about jQuery, what it does, how it's useful, etc.

[Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/learn) has some great tutorials for HTML, Javascript and jQuery.

jQuery UI has some features that might be what you're looking for here, but I'd caution you diving into jQuery UI before you know Javascript and jQuery.

When you're ready look at:

[Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)
and
[Effects](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a very helpful start!  I don't know why I got marked with a bunch of negative votes so quickly... I know my question isn't going to help many other people, but to mark it down so quickly seems kinda mean.  Thank you for you help and for being so quick to provide it.  I'm making you as the best answer!

Comment: Good Answer. Start slow, build up, don't try to fly before you can walk or you'll get frustrated and end up as a cut and paste programmer.