# What is an HTML5 framework?

Tags: html, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

What are HTML5 frameworks? Are bootstrap.js or backbone.js HTML5 frameworks?

What does HTML5 framework mean and can we say if a particular JavaScript framework is HTML5 or not?

Can anyone share a blog etc… to get more understanding of it?

Comment: Sorry, this question is not currently in a format that fits in with the [stackoverflow recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and will probably be closed unless you can edit into a better question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One site that I think provides a good overview of HTML5 is [`Dive into HTML5`](http://diveintohtml5.info/index.html).

Of course there are many more out there that a simple search for "HTML5 introduction tutorial" will find.

[What is the purpose of backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418369/what-is-backbone-js) and [What is Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546709/what-is-bootstrap) have already been answered

Basically, `HTML5` is a language, not a framework, which can be used to markup content in a file that when loaded in a browser can be interpreted and rendered as web page.

[Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) is a framework that runs in the JavaScript engine by the browser on an HTML(5) page. [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) is a set of CSS and HTML templates (and some optional JavaScript extensions) that can be used to create web pages, instead of starting from an empty file.